# Categoricity of the real numbers

Tags: field-theory

Assume we have a field $R \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathrm{card}(R) = 2^{\aleph_0}$. Under what conditions it follows that $R=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The question is too broad. What sort of conditions do you have in mind?

Comment: I mean is it possible to have $R \neq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @user48900 A maximal subfield with $\pi\notin R$ perhaps?

Comment: sure, use Zorn's Lemma to construct a maximal subfield of $\mathbb R$ that does not contain any fixed irrational you want.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27352/a-question-about-fields-of-real-numbers